# JSON se considera inválido

Tags: json

¿Qué errores sintácticos hay en este string JSON?

```
[
  {
    "version": "1.0",
    "features": {
      "caracteristica 1 ",
      "caracteristica 2"
    }
  }
]
```

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: No existe ningún error, es un JsonArray con un JsonObject, que problema tienes?

Answer (score 5):

Estás tratando el objeto `features` cómo un *arreglo*, debes cambiarlo de la siguiente forma:

Cambia las *llaves* `{}` por *corchetes* `[]`

```
[
    {
        "version": "1.0",
        "features": [ 
            "caracteristica 1 ",
            "caracteristica 2"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Solo cómo comentario, yo no pondría la aclaración en sí misma como comentario, ya que lo volvería un JSON inválido de nuevo

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Tienes razón, he editado mi respuesta, gracias por la observación